# Proving a subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A \subset (X,d)$. Prove that $A$ is open iff for every sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \in A$, there exists $n_0 : a_n \in A \space \space \forall \space n\geq n_0$.

My attempt at a solution:

$\implies$ Suppose $A$ is open. Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that $lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \in A$ and call that limit $a$. By hypothesis, there is $r>0$ : $B(a,r) \subset A$. On the other hand, there exists $n_0 : d(a_n,a)<r$ $\space \forall \space n\geq n_0$, but this means $a_n \in B(a,r) \subset A \space \forall \space n\geq n_0$

I am stuck proving the other implication: Suppose for every sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that $lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \in A$, there exists $n_0 : a_n \in A \space \space \forall \space n\geq n_0$. Let $x \in A$, I want to show there is $r>0 : B(x,r) \in A$. I don't know if it's easier to prove it straight forward or by the absurd, in any case, I suppose I must consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with $a_n=x$ for all $n$. I am not so sure where to go from here. I would appreciate any suggestions.

After user113576's idea:

$\longleftarrow$ To prove $A$ is open is equivalent to prove that $A^c$ is closed. Let $x$ be a limit point of $A^c$, then, there exists $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset A^c$ : $x_n \to x$. We want to prove that $x \in A^c$ so, suppose $x \notin A^c \implies x \in A$. By hypothesis, there exists $n_0 : \space \forall \space n\geq n_0$, $x_n \in A$, this means that for $n\geq n_0$, $x_n \in A^c \cap A=\emptyset$, which is clearly absurd. It follows $x \in A^c \implies A^c$ is closed $\implies$ A is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove it the other way.Let a sequence $b_n$ in $A^c$. Then you cannot find such a $n_0$ for this sequence becasue if you could then $A\cap A^c\neq \emptyset$. Prove that the limit will be in $A^c$

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Now I'll write it.